# Hanabi card game: Correctly structuring the deck code

Tags: c#, object-oriented, patterns-and-practices, solid

I'm trying to improve my understanding and ability to write code that uses recommended principles and practices, such as the SOLID principles. To do this, I am implementing the fireworks card game [Hanabi](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/98778/hanabi).

Hanabi has two deck types, Standard and Advanced (which has an extra set of *MultiColour* cards). Each card in a deck  I'm using a `DeckFactory` to construct a `Deck`. I'm looking for feedback on how the code structure could be improved, mostly around the relationship between how the `Deck` class and how the two derived classes (`StandardDeck` and `AdvancedDeck`) relate to each other, and their construction using the `DeckFactory`.

One of my concerns is that `AssembleDeck` (in the parent `Deck` class) needs to be called from each derived class and whether it should be in the `Deck` class at all.

A second concern is the use of a `Stack` to hold the cards; it is more appropriate for drawing a card from the deck, but maybe less so for when the deck is shuffled. I'm thinking of using the Fisher-Yates algorithm for shuffling.

I'm also wondering if there is anything in the code structure that needs to be changed so that unit tests are easier to write.

The card object:

```csharp
public enum Suit { White, Red, Yellow, Green, Blue, MultiColour }
public enum Number { One, Two, Three, Four, Five }

public class FireworksCard {
    public Suit Suit { get; }
    public Number Number { get; }

    public FireworksCard(Suit suit, Number number) {
        Suit = suit;
        Number = number;
    }
}
```

The Deck structure:

```csharp
public interface IDeck {
    FireworksCard DrawCard();
    void Shuffle();
}

public abstract class Deck : IDeck {
    protected Stack<FireworksCard> Cards;

    public bool IsEmpty => !Cards.Any();

    public abstract IEnumerable<Suit> Suit { get; }
    public abstract IEnumerable<Number> Numbers { get; }

    protected void AssembleDeck() {
        Cards = new Stack<FireworksCard>();

        // generate a card for every combination
        foreach (var number in Numbers) {
            int cardRepetitions = GetCardRepetitions(number);

            for (int i = 0; i < cardRepetitions; i++) {
                GenerateAllSuitsForNumber(number);
            }
        }
    }

    private int GetCardRepetitions(Number number) {
        switch (number) {
            case Number.One:
                return 3;
            case Number.Five:
                return 1;
            default:
                return 2;
        }
    }

    private void GenerateAllSuitsForNumber(Number number) {
        foreach (var suit in Suits) {
            Cards.Push(new FireworksCard(suit, number));
        }
    }

    public void Shuffle() {
        // Randomly rearrange the order of Cards
    }

    public FireworksCard DrawCard() {
        return Cards.Pop();
    }
}

public class StandardDeck : Deck {
    public override IEnumerable<Suit> Suits => Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)).Cast<Suit>().Except(new[] { Suit.MultiColour });
    // What's better, this (Number[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Number)); or this
    public override IEnumerable<Number> Numbers => Enum.GetValues(typeof(Number)).Cast<Number>();

    public StandardDeck() {
        AssembleDeck();
    }
}

public class AdvancedDeck : Deck {
    public override IEnumerable<Suit> Suits => Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)).Cast<Suit>();
    public override IEnumerable<Number> Numbers => Enum.GetValues(typeof(Number)).Cast<Number>();

    public AdvancedDeck() {
        AssembleDeck();
    }
}
```

The Deck factory:

```csharp
public enum GameType { Standard, Advanced }

public class DeckFactory {
    public IDeck BuildDeck(GameType gameType) {
        switch (gameType) {
            default:
            case GameType.Standard:
                return BuildStandardDeck();
            case GameType.Advanced:
                return BuildAdvancedDeck();
        }
    }

    private IDeck BuildStandardDeck() {
        return new StandardDeck();
    }

    private IDeck BuildAdvancedDeck() {
        return new AdvancedDeck();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I'm trying to find out if the code structure could be improved upon, mostly around the relationship between how the `Deck` class and the two derived classes relate to each other, and how they are constructed using the `DeckFactory`. I'll add this to the main question.

Comment: Your question might be better suited for [codereview.se] (but don't crosspost).

Comment: @DocBrown I'm always a little confused as to where these sorts of questions are best suited. Are there ways of transferring them to another site?

Comment: @Ayb4btu: I think your question could be on topic on both sites. It is just a suggestion because you *might* get better answers there. Leave it here if the answers you get here are pleasing you. For migration to another site, flag your question for moderator invention, you then can leave a short statement asking for migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code snippets, I would say there is no need for `Deck`s to be this complicated while using both interface and inheritance. If the only difference between decks is that `Advanced` deck has `MultiColour` cards, then have single `Deck` class and two different ways to instantiate it. There is no need for inheritance if their **behavior** is exactly same.

Another thing I would say is that you are focusing on completely wrong thing. You should be working on encoding **rules of the game** into classes. Not worry about `Deck`s.  You should focus on how cards interact with the board and each other.

If I were to do it *top-down TDD*-style, I would start with `Game` class, then I would go through rule-book and implement each rule as single/multiple tests on the `Game` class. If I found out that there is an abstraction to be made, I would extract it out and refactor the code. What you did is to spend quite a lot of time on mostly irrelevant problem and implement it in most complicated way.

Comment: So the two different ways to instantiate the deck would be to have a `Deck` constructor with a single `GameType` parameter, and do away with the factory? Or do you recommend a different way of doing this?

Comment: @Ayb4btu The way I would do it is to have static `CreateBasicDeck` and `CreateAdvancedDeck` on `Deck` class. Both of which will return plain `Deck` class.

Comment: The `Deck` constructor would then have two parameters? One each for the `Suit` and `Number` lists? Also, how would I make it so that `Deck` can only be created as a standard or advanced deck, or is this not a good idea? A quick code example might be helpful.

Comment: @Ayb4btu Yes, basically. And if you make `Deck` constructor private, then it will only can be created from `Create` methods, guaranteeing it can only be created as `Basic` and `Advanced`.

Comment: After your suggestion of a static create method I looked at private constructors. I think what threw me was that [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcfb85a6.aspx) says that they are generally only used in classes that only contain static members. But I guess this is an exception.

Comment: @Ayb4btu It is possible to use private constructor like that, but there is static class for that purpose. Private constructors are generally used if you have static `Create` methods. And maybe when you have complex constructor chain. I see no other reason to use private constructor.